# Python genfromtxt file path

Tags: python, numpy, filepath, genfromtxt

I have an extremely basic problem with the numpy.genfromtxt function. I'm using the Enthought Canopy package: where shall I save the file.txt I want to use, or how shall I tell Python where to look for it? When using IDLE I simply save the file in a preset folder such as C:\Users\Davide\Python\data.txt and what I get is

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.genfromtxt('data.txt')
array([[ 33.1 ,  32.6 ,  18.2 ,  17.9 ],
       [ 32.95,  32.7 ,  17.95,  17.9 ],
       [ 32.9 ,  32.6 ,  18.  ,  17.9 ],
       [ 33.  ,  32.65,  18.  ,  17.9 ],
       [ 32.95,  32.65,  18.05,  17.9 ],
       [ 33.  ,  32.6 ,  18.  ,  17.9 ],
       [ 33.05,  32.7 ,  18.  ,  17.9 ],
       [ 33.05,  32.5 ,  18.1 ,  17.9 ],
       [ 33.  ,  32.6 ,  18.05,  17.9 ],
       [ 33.  ,  32.55,  18.  ,  17.95]])
```

while working with Canopy the same code gives `IOError: data.txt not found`, nor something like `np.genfromtxt('C:\Users\Davide\Python\data.txt')` works. I'm sorry for the question's banality but I'm really going crazy with this. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a fully qualified path but this:

```
np.genfromtxt('C:\Users\Davide\Python\data.txt')
```

won't work because back slashes need to be escaped:

```
np.genfromtxt('C:\\Users\\Davide\\Python\\data.txt')
```

or you could use a raw string:

```
np.genfromtxt(r'C:\Users\Davide\Python\data.txt')
```

As to where the currect saved location is you can query this using `os.getcwd()`:

```
In [269]:

import os
os.getcwd()
Out[269]:
'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.1\\notebooks\\docs'
```